Модели Django. Как импортировать текстовое поле модели во все приложения проекта?
В проекте несколько приложений. Базовые шаблоны отдельно для каждого app.
app1--
templates
--base.html
app2--
templates
--base.html
app3--
templates
--base.html
app4--
templates
--base.html
-models.py
В каждом шаблоне есть повторяющийся html блок содержащий ссылку и текстовое поле:
*<a class="nav__link" href="https://somelink.net">запись на приём</a>*

В app4 есть модель для текстового поля и ссылки.
Как сделать так, чтобы во всех app нужный блок html шаблона base.html менялся при изменении данных модели app4 в админке?
-models.py
from django.db import models

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()\
                        .filter(status=Dikidi.Status.PUBLISHED)


class Dikidi(models.Model):

    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'DF', 'Draft'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'

    title_dikidi = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    dikidi_yaroute = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Dikidi ссылка')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                choices=Status.choices,
                                default=Status.DRAFT)

    
    
    objects = models.Manager() # менеджер, применяемый по умолчанию
    published = PublishedManager() # конкретно-прикладной менеджер
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_dikidi
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dikidi'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dikidi'

-views
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Dikidi


def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Dikidi(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            context = {
                post_list: form.cleaned_data[post_list]
            }
            return render(request, 'dikidi/post/list.html', context)
        else:
            return render(request, 'dikidi/post/list.html', {
                'form': form
            })
    return render(request, 'dikidi/post/list.html', {
       'form': Dikidi()
    })


def post_list(request):
    posts = Dikidi.published.all()
    return render(request,
                    'dikidi/post/list.html',
                    {'posts': posts})

-urls
from django.urls import path
from .import views



app_name = 'dikidi'

urlpatterns = [
    # представления поста
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
]

шаблон app4
{% extends "dikidi/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
    <a href={{ post.dikidi_yaroute }}>записаться на приём</a>
{{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

Понимаю что копать нужно в сторону импорта моделей. Прочитал документацию в соответсвующем разделе. Но КАК КОНКРЕТНО реализовать так и не пойму - def post_list без block content  не работает, а делать отдельное приложение и модели для ссылки и перелапачивать код во всех app слишком долго, да и хотелось бы из админки править одну модель а не все четыре. Подозреваю что решение наверняка есть но вот какое моих нубских мозгов не хватает. Помогите пожалуйста!
PS
Некоторые апдейты по вопросу.
Я добавил представление для отображения обьекта в другом приложении (условно app1), импортировал модель и функцию, написал представление и указал к нему путь.....но поле модели так и не вставляется в шаблон.
Уже голову сломал. Почему не работает?
view
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Partners
from dikidi.models import Dikidi

def dikidi_detail(request, dikidi_id):
    dikidi = Dikidi.objects.get(pk=dikidi_id)
    context = {'dikidi_yaroute': dikidi.dikidi_yaroute}
    return render(request, 'homepage/base.html', context)

urls
from django.urls import path
from .import views
from .views import dikidi_detail



app_name = 'homepage'

urlpatterns = [
    # представления поста
    path('dikidi/<int:dikidi_id>/', dikidi_detail, name='dikidi_detail'),
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
]


вроде еще можно сделать с помощью сигналов? кто то может направить в нужное русло?
